# Combine columns of a matrix to vectors

Tags: matlab, matrix, vector

How can I combine columns of a matrix to vectors?

I have:

```
1 2 3
4 5 6
7 8 9
```

and I want to have a struct with the field 'positions' that contains a vector in each row like this:

```
[1 2 3]
[4 5 6]
[7 8 9]
```

Comment: Do you want to obtain the rows as separate variables (nor recommended)? As a cell array? Why don't you just use `M(1,:)`, `M(2,:)` etc where `M` is the original matrix? Also, your text says "_combine columns_" but the example actually _splits rows_

Comment: Hi thanks for the fast response!

I have a matrix in the beginning and i want to have a struct where each row is a vector and combines the values of the (previous) columns of that matrix

The struct should have the dimension 1xn

Comment: _I want to have a struct where each row is a vector_ => A struct has fields. If `A` has a size of `m x n`, are you looking for 1 struct with `m` fields or an `m x 1` array of structs each with 1 field?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

is this what you need?

```
A=reshape(1:9,[3 3])';
st=cell2struct(mat2cell(A,ones([1 size(A,1)]),size(A,2)),'positions',size(A,2))
```

with that you get struct array.

```
>> st(1).positions

ans =

     1     2     3
```